# Read only the title and/or META tag of HTML file, without loading complete HTML file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, webclient

Scenario :

I need to parse millions of HTML files/pages (as fact as I can) & then read only only Title or Meta part of it & Dump it to Database

What I am doing is using `System.Net.WebClient` Class's `DownloadString(url_path)` to download & then Saving it to Database by LINQ To SQL

But this `DownloadString` function gives me complete html source, I just need only Title part & META tag part.

Any ideas, to download only that much content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can open a stream with this url and use this stream to read the first x bytes, I can't tell the exact number but i think you can set it to reasonable number to get the title and the description.

```
HttpWebRequest fileToDownload = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("YourURL");
            using (WebResponse fileDownloadResponse = fileToDownload.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream fileStream = fileDownloadResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader fileStreamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    {
                        char[] x = new char[Number];
                        fileStreamReader.Read(x, 0, Number);
                        string data = "";
                        foreach (char item in x)
                        {
                            data += item.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can you suggest me an example on this as to how to get Stream & will it help in perfomance ?

Comment: I updated the code with the idea i am trying to tell you about

Answer (score 0):

You can use the verb "HEAD" in a HttpWebRequest to return the the response headers (not  element.  To get the full  element with the meta data you'll need to download the page and parse out the meta data you want.

```
System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri) { Method = "HEAD" };
```

Comment: Will this help in performance as well, or in the background it might download entire page ?

Comment: `HEAD` only returns the response headers; this means HTML meta tags will not be covered if they're not part of the response header, as HTML is in the response body.

Comment: This won't work, because it returns only the http headers. Not the head-part of the html: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4

Comment: BoltClock is right, most likely the meta tags won't be there...  Just do a quick mock to see if they are returned for your pages, if not then you'll need to download the page.  Most likely, you'll end up having to download the page and/or parsing the response stream until you get the <head> elements containing the data needed.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that WebClient will try to download the whole page first, in which case you'd probably want a raw client socket. Send the appropriate HTTP request (manually, since you're using raw sockets), start reading the response (which will not be immediately) and kill the connection when you've read enough. However, the rest will have probably already been sent from the server and winging its way to your PC whether you want it or not, so you might not save much - if anything - of the bandwidth.

Depending on what you want it for, many half decent websites have a custom 404 page which is a lot simpler than a known page. Whether that has the information you're after is another matter.